R plotly: Dropdown menu to update scatter plot quantitative color in plotlyR
I am attempting to generate a UMAP plot with R plotly where you can change how the points are colored by selecting a different variable in the dropdown menu. What I have so far will update how the points are colored, but the colorscale is Red, not the "Set1" color scheme I want, and there is no key displaying what the colors indicate.
This is what I have so far:
vars_df$orig.ident <- as.factor(vars_df$orig.ident)
vars_df$singlr_labels <- as.factor(vars_df$singlr_labels)

# Define dropdown buttons with explicit color mapping
dropdown_buttons <- list(
  list(method = "restyle",
       args = list("marker.color", list(as.numeric(vars_df$orig.ident))),
       label = "orig.ident"),
  list(method = "restyle",
       args = list("marker.color", list(as.numeric(vars_df$singlr_labels))),
       label = "singlr_labels")
)

# Your plot
vars_umap <- plot_ly(data = vars_df,
                     x = ~UMAP_1,
                     y = ~UMAP_2,
                     type = 'scatter',
                     mode = 'markers',
                     alpha = 0.7,
                     marker = list(color = as.numeric(vars_df$orig.ident), colors = "Set1"),
                     showlegend = TRUE
                     
) %>% layout(
  xaxis = list(
    tickvals = 'none',  
    showticklabels = FALSE  
  ),
  yaxis = list(
    tickvals = 'none', 
    showticklabels = FALSE  
  )
) %>%
layout(title = 'UMAP Plot',
       updatemenus = list(
         list(
           buttons = dropdown_buttons,
           direction = "down",
           showactive = TRUE
         )
       ))

vars_umap



